# Is it possible to display arraylist last array element data

Tags: arrays, typescript, arraylist, angular2-template

Is it possible to display ArrayList last array element data

I have ArrayList and want to display only last array data
`this.truckDataPoints = [];`
this is my ArrayList object

this is my data:

```
{
  "jobs" : [ {
    "job_id" : 10,
    "users" : [ {
      "user_id" : 11,
      "data_points" : [ {
        "efficiency" : "good",
        "rev" : 1,
        "probe" : "carboratour",
        "device_id" : "26e09c88237d5342",
        "measurements" : "2",
        "form_id" : "2",
        "instrument" : "plug",
        "background" : "7",
        "surveyed_item_id" : "100",
        "duration" : 0,
        "start_time" : "2017-07-20T04:04:43.000Z",
        "datastream" : "GENERIC",
        "username" : "abc@gmail.com.com"
      }, {
        "efficiency" : "good",
        "rev" : 1,
        "probe_type" : "carboratour",
        "device_id" : "26e09c88237d5342",
        "fixed_measurements" : "2",
        "form_id" : "2",
        "instrument_type" : "plug",
        "background_value" : "7",
        "surveyed_item_id" : "100",
        "duration" : 0,
        "start_time" : "2017-07-20T04:04:43.000Z",
        "datastream" : "GENERIC",
        "username" : "rs022015@gmail.com.com"
      }, {
        "condition" : "good",
        "rev" : 2,
        "type" : "carboratour",
        "device_id" : "26e09c88237d5342",
        "measurements" : "2",
        "form_id" : "2",
        "speed" : "plug",
        "brand" : "7",
        "company" : "100",
        "duration" : 0,
        "start_time" : "2017-07-20T04:04:43.000Z",
        "datastream" : "GENERIC",
        "username" : "rs022015@gmail.com.com"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

I want to display only the last element

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Can you show us the code where you are accessing this JSON? What have you tried?

Comment: //form template
          this.truckTFormDataPoints = [];
    
getDataArray(id) {
 this.dataService.getData(id)
      .subscribe(dataPoints => {
          this.truckTFormDataPoints = (dataPoints as any).jobs[0].users[0].data_points;
               
    }

Comment: which key-value you want to access?

Comment: All, now I am able to access all key and value.

Comment: now, only need to display all keys and value; and every time keys and value are different

Comment: so, please help me how to display it